# Scroll to a div within a modal div

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a modal   `<div class="modal fade" id="hireModal" role="dialog"></div>`

Within this modal I have

```
<div class='modal-dialog'>
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class='modal-content'>
   <div class='modal-header' style='padding:10px 15px;'></div>
  <div class='modal-body' style='padding:5px 10px;'>
    <div id='IwantToScrollToThisDiv'></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
$("#hireModal").animate({ 
scrollTop: $("#IwantToScrollToThisDiv").offset().top
});
```

But it doesn't scroll to that div, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried replicating the same behavior as you would expect.

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rpxowyLq/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").animate({scrollTop: $('#IwantToScrollToThisDiv').offset().top}, 500);
});
```

You should not want `$("#hireModal").animate` instead the body should be animated to give the illusion that the element is scrolled to a positon.

Answer (score -1):

Try animate `.modal-body`

```
$("#hireModal .modal-body").animate({ 
   scrollTop: $("#IwantToScrollToThisDiv").offset().top
});
```

Comment: The answer question box is only for complete answers to the question. This one feels more like a comment (which you will be able to do once you have received enough reputation). Have you run this to ensure it works as the OP intended? If so, remove "Try" and add some text that explains how it solves the issue. It would also be best to put the code into a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).